# Postgres 15 doesn't use index under RLS

Tags: index, postgresql-performance, row-level-security, postgresql-15

Recently, we upgraded the AWS RDS instance from Postgres 12.14 to 15.4 and noticed extremely high disk consumption on the following query
execution:

```
select (exists (select 1 as "one" from "public"."indexed_commit" where 
"public"."indexed_commit"."repo_id" in (964992,964994,964999, ...);
```

For some reason, the query planner starts using Seq Scan instead of the "indexed-commit-repo-idx" index when requesting under user limited with RLS. It happens when there are more than 316 IDs in the IN part of the query. If we execute the request from Superuser, the planner always uses the index (Index Only Scan).

Query plans:

[316 ids under RLS limited user](https://explain.depesz.com/s/X7Iq)

[392 ids under RLS limited user](https://explain.depesz.com/s/lbkX)

[392 ids under Superuser](https://explain.depesz.com/s/uKSG)

What we've already tried:

1. If we add a multicolumn "repo_id, tenant_id" index, the
   planner uses it (Index Only Scan) with any IN params count under RLS.
2. REINDEX CONCURRENT on the "indexed-commit-repo-idx" index didn't help.
3. Planner uses the index if we add `set enable_seqscan = off` before the query execution.

**So the questions are**:

- Why did the planner stop using "indexed-commit-repo-idx" index? Is it a Postgres bug?
- Should we add "tenant_id" to our indexes to force the query planner to use them under RLS?

Postgres version

```
PostgreSQL 15.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6), 64-bit
```

Schema

```
\d indexed_commit
                         Table "public.indexed_commit"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | 
Default
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
  id            | bigint                      |           | not null |
  commit_hash   | character varying(40)       |           | not null |
  parent_hash   | text                        | |          |
  created_ts    | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
  repo_id       | bigint                      |           | not null |
  lines_added   | bigint                      | |          |
  lines_removed | bigint                      | |          |
  tenant_id     | uuid                        |           | not null |
  author_id     | uuid                        |           | not null |
Indexes:
     "indexed-commit-repo-idx" btree (repo_id)
     "indexed_commit_commit_hash_repo_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree 
(commit_hash, repo_id) REPLICA IDENTITY
     "indexed_commit_repo_id_without_loc_idx" btree (repo_id) WHERE 
lines_added IS NULL OR lines_removed IS NULL
Policies:
     POLICY "commit_isolation_policy"
       USING ((tenant_id = 
(current_setting('app.current_tenant_id'::text))::uuid))
```

Table Metadata

```
SELECT relname, relpages, reltuples, relallvisible, relkind, relnatts, 
relhassubclass, reloptions, pg_table_size(oid) FROM pg_class WHERE 
relname='indexed_commit';
     relname     | relpages |  reltuples   | relallvisible | relkind | 
relnatts | relhassubclass | reloptions | pg_table_size
----------------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+----------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------
  indexed_commit | 18170522 | 7.451964e+08 |      18104744 | r |        
9 | f              | 
{autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=200000,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=100000} 
|  148903337984
```

Comment: FWIW, large `IN` lists are known to cause poorly performing queries in most RDBMS. So much so, that I consider them an anti-pattern. Re-writing the query to avoid that will likely be your solution.